# Is it a bad idea to modify a database from a silverlight application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, silverlight

I'm trying to use silverlight to create a simple attendance system. The application will take pictures of users and store them on the server.

I have figured out how to activate the webcam and convert the image to a writeable bitmap. However, I have yet to solve the issue of passing the user id and current date from the asp.net framework to the silverlight application and then executing a set of SQL queries to store data in an SQL server and also saving the webcam image on a server.

However, is it a bad idea, from a performance and security point of view, to execute sql queries from within silverlight?

Comment: How do you aceess a database from Silverlight? What kind of database can you access from Silverlight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a very bad idea.

SilverLight is executing inside of the browser. You don't want to open your database to every browser in the world.

Instead, use a web service. All the browsers call your service, and your service, running on a server, will access the database (running on a different server).

Comment: After reading up on the matter a little more, it does seem like people suggest to use a service to access a database. So can I use the service to execute queries like SELECT and INSERT? Also I thought it should be a straightforward implementation to save an image taken from a webcam on the server. Do I still need to use a service for that? Do you know any links that cover this aspect in particular. My search so far has not been much fruitful.

Comment: Other than using a service, what technology did you think you would use to write to a database from Silverlight?

Comment: I thought I I could pass some connection string to silverlight and then execute the query from within it. But now I know better.

The problem I am having right now is how to transmit a picture from silverlight to a server?

From what I've read up on WCF, I understand that I can expose certain methods and objects TO the silverlight application. But seems like I need a service that takes the byte array from the silverlight and passes it to the server.

Seems like a common task but I can't find any well written articles on it so I came here for some help. What do you think?

Comment: There's nothing special about a byte array. The service you get when you create a SilverLight-enabled WCF service has an operation `void DoWork()`. Change that to `void DoWork(byte[] image)` and you'll have a service that will accept a byte array.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying (I'm marking your response as the answer.) So if I create a file out of the byte[] array and save it locally in the DoWork function then the file will be saved on the server that the WCF is being hosted on?

Comment: Not exactly. You can write a `SaveFile(string fileName, byte[] data)` service operation which would write the bytes to the file.

Answer (score 2):

Bad idea. Silverlight in a browser is client side. I would write a backend service like WCF that handles those issues. Keep the Silverlight clean and light.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the two other answeres on it being a bad idea. First of all, Silverlight does not necessarily run in a browser (see out-of-browser mode) and then also, that has really nothing to do with it:

It would be perfectly legitimate for a WPF browser application running in a corporate intranet to access an sql server hosted within that intranet.

Using Silverlight for that scenario is no different - and intranet line-of-business applications are the most popular use case for Silverlight, so that scenario is anything but contrived.

It is, however, extremely difficult to do since that scenario is not supported. In theory Silverlight could connect to a local sql server, but you'd have to reimplement the sql server protocol (if that's at all open which I don't know) and then presumably port something like entity framework to Silverlight.

Since this is absurdly hard, you're not going to do it and indeed run with the advice by the other answeres and access some web service. Your application then has at least three layers: The Silverlight client, the web service, and the database.

This is called a 3-tier architecture and it's what you usually do with Silverlight applications.

I realize that this answer is somewhat redundant but I wanted to reassure the asker that there is nothing necessarily bad about his idea, other than it not going to be fruitful.